# FOSUserBundle and Java integration

Tags: java, php, symfony, tomcat7, fosuserbundle

I have an application that create and administrate user using 'FOSUserBundle' in 'PHP'.

But now I want to create a Java WebService that should allow these users to login.

How can I reimplement the 'FOSUserBundle' [encoder](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder.php) in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java has implementation of "[PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)" algorithm as "[PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SecretKeyFactory)".

You can import those libs and generate/ check passwords using the same params.

Comment: If you take a look at the implementation of default hash https://github.com/defuse/password-hashing/blob/master/PasswordHashClass.php you can see that is a little different from the implementation I put on the question. The results doesn't match.